# How to run two separate INSERT INTO statements with one WITH in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get data once at the start of my transaction with a `WITH` statement, and then branch that data out into two more `WITH` statements that I can use to make two `INSERT INTO` statements.

Looks like this:

```
BEGIN;

WITH data AS (...),
data1 AS (SELECT * FROM data ...),
data2 AS (SELECT * FROM data ...);

INSERT INTO table1 (...) (...);
INSERT INTO table2 (...) (...);

COMMIT;
```

I'm getting that there's a syntax error with the `;` after my `WITH` statements, and when I remove it, it says `data2` doesn't exist...

How can I get my intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Just use CTEs:

```
WITH data AS (...),
     data1 AS (SELECT * FROM data ...),
     data2 AS (SELECT * FROM data ...),
     i as (INSERT INTO table1 (...) (...))
INSERT INTO table2 (...) (...);
```

Postgres allows `insert`/`update`/`delete` in CTEs (although they are commonly used with `RETURNING` to return the affected rows).

Answer (score -1):

Any reason you need to do it in parallel?

```sql
BEGIN;

WITH data AS (...),
data1 AS (SELECT * FROM data ...),
data2 AS (SELECT * FROM data ...)
INSERT INTO table1 (...) (...);

WITH data AS (...),
data1 AS (SELECT * FROM data ...),
data2 AS (SELECT * FROM data ...)
INSERT INTO table2 (...) (...);

COMMIT;
```

If this is unacceptable for performance reasons, then there is possibly some general db design choices you should reconsider/create a virtual table that can handle it.